# codeigniter multiple ckeckbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I'm trying to get multiple checkbox values I get the last value always not all of it I tried to check if it array but it's single value

```
<?php echo form_open('user/favorit_cats');?>
    <h1>please select the food cateogry you want to see it the most</h1>

 <?php 
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($cats_names);$i++){
        echo'<input type="checkbox" name="meal_cat" value='.$cats_id[$i].'>';
        echo '<label for="'.$cats_id[$i].'">'.$cats_names[$i].'</label><br>';

    }
    ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit','set as favorit'); ?>
    </form>
```

and my controller

```
 if($this->input->post('subm it')){
               if(is_array($this->input->post['meal_cat'])){
                   echo'array';
               }
            }
```

I want to get all the values that checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the input name as an array and then you can access all checked boxes using the var itself which would then be an array.

Set the name in the form to `meal_cat[]` and you will be able to access all the checkboxes as an array.

```
$this->input->post('meal_cat');
```

It will be an array, the same thing as `$_POST['meal_cat']`.
To Print the array:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['meal_cat'])) 
{
    print_r($_POST['meal_cat']); 
}
?>
// OR

<?php 
if (isset($this->input->post('meal_cat'))) 
{
    print_r($this->input->post('meal_cat')); 
}
?>
```

And if you want that data in the comma separated list then it try `implode`

```
echo implode(',', $this->input->post('meal_cat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

On html form if you want pass input as array, you should name it as an array. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="var[]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing name :

Instead of meal_cat in :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="meal_cat" value='.$cats_id[$i].'>';
```

Change by meal_cat[] :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="meal_cat[]" value='.$cats_id[$i].'>';
```

And in your php use this variable as array.